# awk command: if line doesn't starts with a character remove new line on before line

Tags: string, unix, awk, data-manipulation

Trying to use awk command to implement this rule: if line doesn't starts with "O|" or "A|" or "S|" I want to remove new line on before line

I have this file in input (input.txt)

```
O|field1|field2
O|field1|
field2
A|field1|
field2
S|field1|
field2
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
O|field1|
field2
A|field1|
field2
S|field1|
field2
O|field1|field2
```

I want this output

```
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
A|field1|field2
S|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
A|field1|field2
S|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
```

Executing this code

`awk '/^O\|/ || /^A\|/ || /^S\|/ {printf "%s", $0; next} 1 {print}' input.txt > output.txt`

It returns

```
O|field1|field2O|field1|field2
A|field1|field2
S|field1|field2
O|field1|field2O|field1|field2O|field1|field2
A|field1|field2
S|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
```

Somebody can help me please?

Answer (score 4):

This `awk` should work for you:

```bash
awk -F'|' 'NF==3 && $3 == "" {p = $0; next}
      {print (NF == 1 ? p $1 : $0); p = ""}' file

O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
A|field1|field2
S|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
A|field1|field2
S|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
```

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
!/\|/ {
  print val,$0
  val=""
  next
}
$0~/\|$/ && NF==3{
  val=$0
  next
}
1
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, which tests the layout of the records, might be better for you than testing the values of the fields:

```
$ awk -v RS='([^|]*[|]){2}[^|]*\n' '{$0=RT; gsub(/\n/,""); print}' file
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
A|field1|field2
S|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
A|field1|field2
S|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS to just define a  record as being 3 fields separated by `|`s and ending in a newline, then removes any newlines from each record before printing it.

Answer (score 3):

You only seem to have the issue with a missing last field.

If the `|` is the field delimiter, you can check if the 3rd field is not empty and print the whole line.

Print the previous line plus the current line if field 1 is not `A` `O` or `S`

```
awk -F'|' '{
  if($1 !~ /^[AOS]$/) { print p $0; next }
  if ($3!="") print $0
  p = $0
}' file
```

Output

```
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
A|field1|field2
S|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
A|field1|field2
S|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
```

Answer (score 3):

another solution

```
awk -v RS="" '{gsub("\\|\n","|")}1' file

O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
A|field1|field2
S|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
A|field1|field2
S|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
```

treat the file as one long stream and remove the newlines after the pipes.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk NF=NF RS= OFS=\| FS='[|]\n'
> {  g,n}awk NF=NF RS= OFS=\| FS='\\|\n' 
> {m    }awk NF=NF RS= OFS=\| FS='\|\n'
> ```

```
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
A|field1|field2
S|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
A|field1|field2
S|field1|field2
O|field1|field2
```

Comment: Interesting solution, can you explain a bit how this works? What does `NF=NF` do, and can you only place this at the beginning?

Comment: @Thefourthbird : `NF = NF` is same as what others do with `$1=$1`, but u can safely type in that in the console terminal, unquoted. `mawk`s take command line assignments as is regarding backslashes, while `gawk` and `nawk` treats them just like any double quoted string inside the main code, thus necessitating  double backslashes, as u can see in the 2 diff variants of `FS`. If you place any of the stuff after `NF=NF` to its left, you must also add the `-v` flag prefix, e.g. `-v OFS=…`. Doing it after the main code allows for skipping that part, but those are processed …..

Comment: ….. after all `BEGIN { }` sections, if any, but prior to `NR == 1`. Setting `RS` to blank means all chunks of input without entirely zero length blank lines in between get processed at once, and I simply swapped the roles of `FS` and `RS`, and use `FS + OFS` to fix the formatting issue. So these solutions are designed for inputs that aren't continuously piped in in nature.

Comment: @Thefourthbird : `$1 = $1` is actually a problematic form ::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::: `echo '   abc xyz ' | mawk '$1=$1' FS='[ ]+'` :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::: prints absolutely nothing, because `$1` is actually an empty string, and `"abc"` resides in `$2`. the assignment is same as doing `$1 = ""`, which means the pattern is evaluating an empty string to boolean `FALSE`, thus no default action of `{ print }` is being performed. `NF=NF` fixes that issue, keeping in mind that it still skips empty rows since `NF` is zero

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -rz 's/\|\n([^OAS])/\|\1/g' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
awk '/^[OAS]\|/ {if (l){print l}l=$0;next} {l=l $0} END {print l}' inputFile
```

The variable `l` represents the line we are building.

If the input begins with the special character, then print `l` (if it is not empty). Otherwise, start building the line up. The `END` is run after all lines are processed to print out the last version of `l`.